# pinterest-like 'choose your favourite topics' (server side)

Tags: php

My project is to create a website which allows users to create their blogs and posts, comment and so on.
I'd like the user to be able to choose 3 topics of his interest and for each one of them, also three 'sub-topics'. The idea is something like what happens when you register on pinterest, so that the home page is kinda 'customized' depending on what you like.
So the topics (which are already in a table) must be registered in a table linked to the user who chosed them (interests table attributes: username, id_topic1, id_topic2...)

The client side selection works fine (the user selects images), but I' cant manage to pass the value of the selected interests (which I have saved in an array, named x) to my php page, to save them in the db and use after to filter results in the homepage.

I hope I've been clear enough(I'm pretty new to coding..)!
Thanks in advance!

Here below I'm posting the js code I have for this 'interest board' selection-> this works but I can't pass var x to php!

JS function

```
function gestoreConferma(){
  try{
    var j=0;
    var prov;
    while ( j < 3 ) {
        for (var i = 0; i < nodiSottoArgomenti.length; i++) {
          if (nodiSottoArgomenti[i].style.border=='4px solid red'){
            x[j]= nodiSottoArgomenti[i].id;
            prov = x[j];
            window.location.href = "http://localhost/Sito/interessi.php?sottointeresse="+x;
            j++;
          }  
        } 
    }
  }
  catch(e){
      alert('gestoreConferma' + e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your whole approach makes little sense to begin with - trying to change the main window location multiple times in a loop can’t work, the browser will break off any running scripts when it changes the location the first time. You should collect all your data first, and then send it to the server using one single request.

Comment: uh sorry I think I pasted here the old version! actually I moved the window location out of the loop cause it clearly didn't make sense. The url has in it the values i need to pass to the php page, so that seems to work, but then when I try to echo $_GET['x'] I get nothing.. thanks for the answer anyway! what I'm wondering is if there are even totally different ways to create the 'table of interests' that I'm imagining